# Is it possible to enable autocomplete/autofill for a select tag?

Tags: html, autocomplete, html-select

There is special personal information stored in the browser that auto-fills forms. For instance if there is a form with first, last, city and state and the user selects autocomplete when they type in their first then last, city and state will autofill.

But I think this only works for HTML `input` tags. Is there any way to make this auto-fill work for HTML select tags? In other words, is there any way to make the auto-fill work if I change the state input from an `input` tag to a `select` tag?

Answer (score 0):

so if I'm understanding correctly you want an auto-fill on a select tag (drop-down). This has to be done via Javascript I believe. HTML & CSS won't let you manage this sort of action.

You could try the following:

HTML:

```
<input id="someinput">
<br>
<select id="states">
    <option value="1">NY</option>
    <option value="2">California</option>
    <option value="3">Florida</option>
    <option value="4">Boston</option>
    <option value="5">Texas</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#states{
    height:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var opts = $('#states option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
    $('#someinput').keyup(function () {
        var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
        var optlist = $('#states').empty();
        opts.each(function () {
            if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
                optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Check out the http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VeLKW/227/